# Calculate average ignoring blank cells which also contain formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am having trouble with the final Grand Total Average calculation to ignore  “blank” and “zero” from the group of sub totals from the above columns.The blank cells also contain a formula.

I only want the calculations to include the cells that actually have a number in them to be included in the Grand Total Average.

My individual calculation is = =IFERROR((M276),"") which shows a “blank” if no data in the cells ---- (All GOOD)

My sub total formula is = =AVERAGEIF(M292:M304,"<>,0") which shows a “blank” if no data in the cells ---- (I'm not sure if this is correct -?)

My Grand Total formula is = =AVERAGEIF((M34,M68,M102,M136,M170,M204,M238,M272,M306),"<>0") --- ( Error #VALUE!)

I have also tried = =AVERAGE((N34,N68,N102,N136,N170,N204,N238,N272,N306),"<>") & ("") & ("<>,0") on the end

The result in the grand total cell is and error message  = #VALUE!

I have also used =IFERROR(AVERAGE(M34,M68,M102,M136,M170,M204,M238,M272,M306)," ") which at least gives me a number, but int doesn't exclude the blank cells.

Can you assist me please?

Comment: Unfortunately this Question has not been edited properly. Expecting more corrections !!

Answer (score 0):

**Check the Screen Shot below,,**

[image]

**NB:** *My Solution is below written Array Formula produces 24.9,, as Result.*

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(M34:M306),M34:M306))}
```

finish this with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**Note,** The value in RED has the modified Formula what your have tried.

```
=AVERAGEIF(M34:M306,">0")
```

Here, instead of "<>0" I've used ">0" but look the difference in Result.

*Last one is simple AVERAGE formula just to Test the Result*.

**So,, use my the FIRST Formula as perfect Solution.**

*Hope this help you & the Readers too.*